# mvn install:install-file is unable to install ojdbc7.jar at correct location

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having difficulty in getting this `ojdbc7` JAR file installed in the correct location. I tried the following from Windows 10 command prompt and got the  `BUILD SUCCESS` message as shown below:

```
C:\Users\john>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing C:\ojdbc7.jar to C:\Users\l-john\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.1\ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.381 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-24T12:09:04-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I went inside the `12.1.0.1` folder (located here `C:\Users\john\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.1`) I only saw the following files : 
[image]

For one of my Maven project, eclipse(version 2018-19) is trying to access the JAR file and I keep getting following `BUILD FAILURE` message which is obvious since the file isn't there:

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.208 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-24T12:15:39-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.ii:MyProject:war:0.1: Could not find artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1 in spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

In my `pom.xml`, I do have the dependency defined as follows:

[image]

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to perform some additional testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that in mvn install command -DgroupId is not correct, instead of giving **"-DgroupId=com.oracle.jdbc"**, you have given just **"-DgroupId=com.oracle"**

Answer (score 0):

Maven tells you it is installing the jar to

C:\Users\l-john\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.1\ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar

But you are looking at

C:\Users\john\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.1

l-john vs john

Comment: Yeah. `l-john` is the admin account's username and I am operating under normal user `john` account. For example, if I ever need admin rights to install any software, I have to type admin user name as `l-john` and then admin password, to install other things

Comment: You are right actually. When, I went inside the `l-john` folder and traced down the path, I saw the JAR folder there. Is there a way, to have it installed inside `john` folder instead of `l-john` ? Because, my eclipse is referring to `john` folder only, instead of `l-john`.

Comment: did you open the cmd as admin? try it without. or execute the command in eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying cmd as admin. Trying without it. Good point.

Comment: also be aware of the answer from VAP. your dependency definition is wrong. you have to use com.oracle as groupId when you install it with -DgroupId=com.oracle

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks. Running without Admin worked and I got rid of the error.

Comment: @John Re "_Is there a way, to have it installed inside john folder instead of l-john ?_" see [Maven / Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values): `<localRepository>`.